# Apps disappearing from purchased section in App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, ios-appstore

When you download an app, and it gets taken off the App Store, aren’t you still able to download it from the purchased section in the App Store? This usually works for most apps (Ex: I can still download Flappy Bird from my purchased section) but some apps that I got a while ago don’t appear in the purchased section anymore.

One example is when a screen recording app called Anyscreen was put on the App Store. I got it before it was taken off the App Store, and deleted it a few days later, but later I noticed that I could no longer find it in the purchased section? Is there a way to still get these apps?

Comment: You used to be able to re-sync it from iTunes if the actual .ipa was on your Mac, but idk if that still applies, as they're been making the entire structure more & more reliant on OTA. I specifically stayed on iTunes 12.6.3 to avoid that reliance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot re-download a purchased app from the App Store if either the developer or Apple has removed it from sale.

Once removed from the App Store, it also gets removed from your list of purchased apps.

Comment: It wasn’t a paid app, so I don’t think it should be a problem?

Comment: "Purchased" doesn't necessarily mean "paid for" it just means "acquired".